# Defining scope variables in Angular view is OK?

Tags: angularjs

This is an Angular application and I have an html page which contains the below code segment.

```
<div ng-click="openPopup()">
<div>{{getDisplayText()}}</div>
</div>
```

- openPopup() - open the popup
- getDisplayText() - get the displaying text

now I need the displayText() method value to be used in the openPopup() method

So I changed the code segment to this

```
<div ng-click="openPopup(displayValue)">
<div>{{displayValue = getDisplayText()}}</div>
</div>
```

I am defining a variable in the HTML page. This actually works fine. But I just need to verify

1. defining the scope variable "displayValue" in the HTML page is OK in performance wise or in a best practice ?

Comment: It's not ok. For performance reasons too. I can't see any good reason to do it. Move it to controller.

Comment: Set you data on the `openPopup` function call for popup. Now, you are getting data from controller `getDisplayText()` and again it passing to controller as parameter, not making seance.

Comment: no you should create variable in controller

Comment: @Sachink, because otherwise you have to call the getDisplayText() to retrieve the details again within the openPopup() method. This is just to prevent calling the getDisplayText() method again

Comment: @dfsq, If we move the variable to the controller, At when, we are gonna call getDisplayText() method and set the variable. Let's just think of a situation like that. So defining the variable in the controller does not help much here right ?

Comment: The expression is legal, but the function will be called every digest cycle, possibly multiple times. This can be easily verified by adding a `console.log` inside the function. If your goal is to reduce the number of times a function is called, it should be done in a controller.

Answer (score 1):

You can call getDisplayText() and assign the value to a scope variable in openPopup function inside controller. This variable can be used be displayed in HTML. Code for reference...

```
<div ng-click="openPopup()">
 <div>{{someText}}</div>
</div>

$scope.someText = "Some Text!"
function getDisplayText() {
   return "New Text!";
}
$scope.openPopup = function() {
  $scope.someText = getDisplayText();
}
```

Comment: This has an issue. The someText will be set if you only open the popup :(

Comment: You can call getDisplayText() again for setting the text in variable in controller.